# Not getting console.log when looping through an object in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm using vue to do my frontend, but I'm having a problem in my computed property method and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I have an object that looks like this

```
Product1: {
    price_1: 123,
    price_2: 234
}
Product2: {
    price_1: 123,
    price_2: 234
}
```

What I'm trying to do is that I would like to loop through them and grab the price data and then calculate the price_1 and price_2 for each product.

The problem I'm having is that when I do this

```
Object.keys(this.productPrices).reduce((v, k) => {
    console.log(k);
});
```

My `console.log` isn't showing up.

Here is my whole code

```js
<template>
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="text-center">Products</div>

                                            {{ productPricesList }}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    props: ['user'],
    data(){
        return {
            products: [],
            productPrices: {}
        }
    },
    computed:{
        productPricesList(){
            Object.keys(this.productPrices).reduce((v, k) => {
                console.log(k);
            });
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getProducts(){
            axios.get(`/api/products/${this.user.id}/product-prices`).then(response => {
                this.products = response.data.products;

                this.products.forEach(i => {
                    this.productPrices[i.name] = {
                        price_1: 0,
                        price_2: 0
                    };
                });
            });
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getProducts();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is equal to `this.productPrices` in `productPricesList()`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. At the moment I would like to get the values from the loop

Comment: What does `this.products` produce when you console.log it?